# Class library Image path

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, class

so I am strangely stuck on something which sounds rather simple, I wonder if this fine community can help me figure this one out. I am using c# and asp.net with a sqlserver 2012 backend

I have a class library with multiple folders in one folder is a class I am working on. This class queries the db to basically get blob data. This is stored in a datatable and it is returned whatever calls it (currently a web app, but i want to use it for api calls as well).

now within the datatable I need to create thumbnails for things that are not images (audio, video files etc). I have a few default ones and I thought the best way is to convert it into an array add it to my datatable to whatever calls it can use it if wanted.

The default images are in an image folder in the same library, but I am struggling to get to the image. I have tried allsorts from looking online but none of it actually gets to the directory i need it. Naturally i do not want to hard code the full path for when this is published.

```
Class library
 - Folder A 
   - Class 1
   - Class 2 (class trying to find image 1)
 - Folder B (images)
   - Image 1
   - Image 2 

Web app
 - Folder 1
  - aspx page a
  - aspx page b (calling class 2 to get images and calls aspx page c to display images)
  - aspx page c (display images passed to it)
 - folder 2

api app
 - procedure 1 (calls class 2 to get images)
 - procedure 2
```

What I have here is class 2 which builds up the datatable for the images and returns it to whatever calls it. I basically want it to find the current folder structure when I am in the library (class 2) from there I can add the rest of the path to the image in folder B.

thanks

Comment: Right click on the image, click properties and ensure it is copied to the bin folder.

Comment: ok so i changed it to add the images to the bin directory by changing copy if newer to the images. That has added the images to the bin. But how do i get to them from within the class itself

Comment: You can get them by accessing the path where your executable is located. Alternatively, you can make change them to a resource, in which case they will become part of your exe file.

Comment: ... or you get them with an absolute path. Btw: You have to remember that you can´t get the path of the source class at run-time. You´ll always end up in some bin folter where your app is being executed. What you can do is to determine the name of the class of the object currently executing your code via reflection.

Comment: Perhaps the simplest thing would be to encode the PNG data as a data url, forget the files etc, just have some strings in your app

Comment: Interesting..., I have tried using reflection but end up now where near the files, however as suggested by @CaiusJard maybe that is the way to go. I could convert the images to bytes and then base64 it and store that in the app